# To change the value of a variable in a function abc executed by multiprocessing according to a variable in function xyz

Tags: python, function, multiprocessing

If I run function a by multiprocessing and just run function b, I want the data value of function b to affect the data value of function a

But it doesn't go my way and hasn't been able to solve this problem for more than five hours
pls help me

I want to be modified in the code below

```
def abc(data):
    print(data.value)
    time.sleep(2)
    while True:
        print(data.value)
        time.sleep(1)

def xyz():
    global data
    while True:
        data = random.random()
        time.sleep(0.5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = multiprocessing.Value("d", random.random())
    p = mp.Process(target=abc,args=(data,))
    p.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    xyz()
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```python
        data = random.random()
```

Is changing the variable data to a new value.  `data`, however, is a shared memory reference, if you want to update it, you need to use `.value`:

```python
        data.value = random.random()
```

This will update the value in the shared memory, and marshal it to any processes that have a reference.

Comment: wow thx I don't know how many hours I haven't solved this simple thing